# design a graph where shortest path tree is longer than minimum spanning tree

Tags: algorithm, graph, graph-algorithm, shortest-path, minimum-spanning-tree

Design an example of a graph where the [shortest path tree](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Shortest-path_tree) is longer than the minimum spanning tree.

In the worst case, how much longer can the shortest path tree be than the
minimum spanning tree?

Comment: How do you define the length of a tree? As far as I know, trees have height, not length. Is it the same?

Answer (score 1):

Consider the following graph, where the cost of an edge is written between braces:

```
1
|
|(1)
|
2
| \
|  \
|   \
|    \
|(25) \ (10)
|      \
3-------4     
   (20)
```

Then the shortest path tree rooted at vertex 1 is:

```
1
|
|(1)
|
2
| \
|  \
|   \
|    \
|(25) \ (10)
|      \
3       4
```

while the minimum spanning tree of the graph is:

```
1
|
|(1)
|
2
  \
   \
    \
     \
      \ (10)
       \
3-------4     
   (20)
```

As for your second question, I could not think of an answer.

Answer (score 1):

To answer your second question : If the graph has n vertices, the length of the shortest-path tree is L, and the length of the minimum spanning tree is K, then L <(n-1)K, but L can be arbitrarily close to (n-1)K. To see why L < (n-1)K : each edge in the shortest-path tree is less than the length of the minimum spanning tree. There are (n-1) of them, therefore the length of the shortest-path tree is less than (n-1)K. But the difference can be arbitrarily small.

Consider the graph where vertex 1 is at distance M, a very large number, from vertex 2,...,n. The distances of any two vertices among 2,...,n are very small number e. Then the length of the short-path tree rooted at 1 is (n-1)M, whereas the length of the minimum spanning tree is (n-2)e + M. The ratio is approximately (n-1) when e is very small and M is very large.